# In-memory cache class

Tags: java

The following is a simple cache that I have written in java. It uses the LRU replacement policy and also evicts items based on a refresh interval (default 5 secs). Right now, the class is not thread safe but would like to add that functionality in the future.

```
 class Cache<K,V>{
    private final HashMap<K,V> cacheLookup;
    private final LinkedList<CacheEntry<K,V>> cacheList;
    private int capacity = 1024;
    private boolean autoRefresh = true;
    private long refreshInterval = 5_000_000_000L;

    public Cache() {
        cacheLookup = new HashMap<>(capacity);
        cacheList = new LinkedList<>();
        triggerAutoRefresh();
    }

    public Cache(int capacity){
        this.capacity = capacity;
        cacheLookup = new HashMap<>(capacity);
        cacheList = new LinkedList<>(); 
        triggerAutoRefresh();
    }

    public void put(K key, V value) {       
            if(cacheList.size()>=capacity)
                evictItem();

            cacheLookup.put(key,value);
            cacheList.add(new CacheEntry<>(key,value,refreshInterval));     
    }
    
    public V get(K key) {       
        return cacheLookup.get(key);        
    }
    
    public boolean containsKey(K key) {
        return cacheLookup.containsKey(key);
    }

    public int size() {
        return cacheList.size();
    }
    
    public void clear() {
        cacheLookup.clear();
        cacheList.clear();
    }
    
    public void view() {
        for(CacheEntry<K,V> entryItem: cacheList)
            System.out.println("Key: "+entryItem.key+" | Value: "+entryItem.value);
    }
    
    public void setRefreshInterval(long refreshInterval) {
        this.refreshInterval = refreshInterval;
    }
    
    public void setAutoRefresh(boolean autoRefresh) {
        this.autoRefresh = autoRefresh;
    }

    private void evictItem() {
        CacheEntry<K,V> item = cacheList.removeFirst();
        cacheLookup.remove(item.key);
    }

    private void triggerAutoRefresh() {
        Runnable backgroundEvictionTask = ()->{
            while(autoRefresh) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(refreshInterval);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                
                while(!cacheList.isEmpty() && !cacheList.peekFirst().isAlive())
                    evictItem();
            }
        };

        Thread evictorThread = new Thread(backgroundEvictionTask);
        evictorThread.setDaemon(true);
        evictorThread.start();
    }
}

class CacheEntry<K,V>{
    K key;
    V value;
    private long createdTime, lifeSpan;
    
    public CacheEntry(K key, V value,long lifeSpan) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
        this.createdTime = System.nanoTime();
        this.lifeSpan = lifeSpan;
    }

    public boolean isAlive() {
        return System.nanoTime() - this.createdTime + 1 > this.lifeSpan ;
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate if you could share your feedback about the implementation.

Comment: Why does the entry in the lru list also have the value? That seems an unneeded reference

Comment: It is not an LRU cache. The _use_ (`get`) shall move the item up.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I have rolled back Rev 2 → 1. Please see [_What should I do when someone answers my question?

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Looks good to me, but a few suggestions.

### Use `record`s

Your `CacheEntry` class can be replaced with an inner `record` class:

```java
public class Cache<K, V> {
    record CacheEntry<K, V>(K key, V value, long deadAt) {
        public boolean isAlive() {
            return System.nanoTime() < deadAt;
        }
    }
//...
        cacheList.add(new CacheEntry<>(key, value, System.nanoTime() + refreshInterval));
```

### Use synchronization for thread-safety

Simply use an `Object` on which to synchronize on:

```java
        Runnable backgroundEvictionTask = () -> {
            while (autoRefresh) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(refreshInterval);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                synchronized (cacheList) {
                    while (!cacheList.isEmpty() && !cacheList.peekFirst()
                            .isAlive())
                        evictItem();
                }
            }
        };
```

### Use `ArrayDeque` for the list

Instead of using `LinkedList<CacheEntry<K, V>> cacheList`, you could replace it with `ArrayDeque`, wich is a bit faster in this case.

### Minor issues

Use `final` modifiers if appropriate.

### Supplement

I forgot something. As @rob-audenaerde mentioned, there is no need to hold the value twice/doubly.

And also

```java
    public void put(K key, V value) {       
            if(cacheList.size()>=capacity)
                evictItem();

            cacheLookup.put(key,value);
            cacheList.add(new CacheEntry<>(key,value,refreshInterval));     
    }
```

must be synchronized on the same level.

So we have:

```java
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Cache<K, V> {
    record CacheEntry<K>(K key, long deadAt) {
        public boolean isAlive() {
            return System.nanoTime() < deadAt;
        }
    }

    private final HashMap<K, V> cacheLookup;
    private final ArrayDeque<CacheEntry<K>> cacheList;
    private final int capacity;
    private boolean autoRefresh = true;
    private long refreshInterval = 5_000_000_000L;

    public Cache() {
        this(1024);
    }

    public Cache(final int capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
        cacheLookup = new HashMap<>(capacity);
        cacheList = new ArrayDeque<>(capacity);
        triggerAutoRefresh();
    }

    public synchronized void put(final K key, final V value) {
        if (cacheList.size() >= capacity) {
            evictItem();
        }
        cacheList.add(new CacheEntry<>(key, System.nanoTime() + refreshInterval));
        cacheLookup.put(key, value);
    }

    public synchronized V get(final K key) {
        return cacheLookup.get(key);
    }

    public synchronized boolean containsKey(final K key) {
        return cacheLookup.containsKey(key);
    }

    public synchronized int size() {
        return cacheList.size();
    }

    public synchronized void clear() {
        cacheLookup.clear();
        cacheList.clear();
    }

    public synchronized void view() {
        for (final CacheEntry<K> entryItem : cacheList) {
            System.out.println("Key: " + entryItem.key + " | Value: " + cacheLookup.get(entryItem.key));
        }
    }

    public void setRefreshInterval(final long refreshInterval) {
        this.refreshInterval = refreshInterval;
    }

    public void setAutoRefresh(final boolean autoRefresh) {
        this.autoRefresh = autoRefresh;
    }

    private synchronized void evictItem() {
        CacheEntry<K> item = cacheList.removeFirst();
        cacheLookup.remove(item);
    }

    private void triggerAutoRefresh() {
        Runnable backgroundEvictionTask = () -> {
            while (autoRefresh) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(refreshInterval);
                } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return;
                }

                synchronized (Cache.this) {
                    while (!cacheList.isEmpty() && !cacheList.peekFirst()
                            .isAlive()) {
                        evictItem();
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        Thread evictorThread = new Thread(backgroundEvictionTask);
        //evictorThread.setDaemon(true);
        evictorThread.start();
    }
}
```

### Sidenote

There is no guarantee that `get` returns a valid value after `containsKey` has returned true (and vice versa). So, remove the `containsKey` method.

Answer (score 2):

I fail to think of arguments supporting synchronisation, the implementation seems already thread safe with calculated risk, that is the cost of synchronise clearing the lookup and the cache over the benefits. To avoid the synchronisation overhead just reverse the order of putting values in the cache, put cache entries in the `cacheList` and then in the `cacheLookup`...

```
public void put(K key, V value) {

        ...

        cacheList.add(new CacheEntry<>(key,value,refreshInterval));
        cacheLookup.put(key,value);
}
```

...it might also worth testing whether the cache already contains the `key` to put and if so evict the cache entry before putting the new `value`.
 
 
 
The implementation is almost LRU considering the implementation of `put` method evicts first element...

```
public void put(K key, V value) {       
        if(cacheList.size()>=capacity)
            evictItem();

        cacheLookup.put(key,value);
        cacheList.add(new CacheEntry<>(key,value,refreshInterval));     
}
```

... a LRU implementation is time sensitive, it should evict the least recently used element.

Answer (score 2):

While others have already given some inspiration on where to improve your code, I want to take a bit of a different approach.

#### Making use of SoftReference's

First, let's quickly discuss what a cache is and what it should do. The cache primary concern is to store objects temporarily usually to avoid costly lookups and such things. As such, a cache is nice to have. While often caches have an artificial limitation in the number of objects they may hold there isn't a real limitation on the size the value can really have. I.e. if I initialize a cache that can only hold up to 3 entries before starting to evict the least recently used nothing prevents me to add objects in the 10 gigabyte range that basically will lead to an OutOfMemory error. A common recommentation for caches is therefore to make use of mechanisms that allow the garbage collector to free space that may be nice to have quick access to but that is not fundamental important for the applications health. Java i.e. has this concept of soft references. A soft reference is similar to a strong reference which you normally get by initializing a new object via the `new` keyword (or if you so desire via reflection and the `newInstance(...)` method). A soft reference is initialized like any other object via

```java
SoftReference<V> valRef = new SoftReference<>(value);
...
V value = valRef.get();
```

This is enough to tell the JVM if your application runs short on memory objects which are only softly reachable can be collected by the GC to free up some needed memory. A cache is always an intermediary solution meaning that if a value isn't there you need to call some other operation that provides that data then, and this is exactly what is needed then. Your application run short on memory, GC freed up some values that were present in your cache and so you need to calculate these values again.

Adding soft references therefore to your implementation would be a first suggestion I'd take into consideration.

#### Keep the API clean and expressive

Next, the purpose of the cache is to store some data for some later access and as such it needs methods for adding and retrieving values. Usually people are not that interested in what is exactly available in the store right now or how many objects the cache currently holds and so forth.

IMO, the API of a cache therefore only needs something like

```
Cache<K, V> cache = new Cache<>(capacity);
cache.put(key, value);
cache.put(key, value, Duration.ofDays(3));
V value = cache.get(key);
```

anything other is not that important in first place for a cache.

Especially instead of providing a long value that could be either a millisecond or nanosecond value a more clear approach is always beneficial IMO. While adding a new entry to the cache you could i.e. use the suggested `Duration` object like this:

```java
// validTill agument was initialized like this:
// Duration validTill = Duration.ofDays(3);

Instant _validTill;
if (validTill != null) {
   _validTill = Instant.now().plus(validTill);
} else {
   _validTill = null;
}
...
SoftReference<V> newNode = new SoftReference<>(new CacheEntry<>(key, value, _validTill));
this.lookupMap.put(key, newNode);
this.entryList.addFirst(newNode);
```

Later on you can simply check whether the entry is to old to keep in the cache like this:

```java
...
Instant validTill = entry.get().validTill();
if (validTill != null) {
    Instant now = Instant.now();
    if (validTill.isBefore(now)) {
        evictEntry(entry);
    }
}
...
```

Especially when you design some API it is always a good approach to document things like whether the implementation is thread-safe, may return null values or whether non-null objects are expected as input. Through annotations, i.e. in the `javax.annotation` package like `@Nonnull`, `@Nullable` or in the `javax.annotation.concurrent` package like `@ThreadSafe` or `@NotThreadSafe` you cann add that information quite easily and most IDEs will bring up some warnings if you i.e. try to add an object that might become null to a method that stated that it expects non-null values and the like.

#### Real-time update necessary?

The last point I quickly want to discuss is whether real-time updates of the cache are really necessary. Adding a thread that removes entries from the list forces you to add synchronization to your inner map and list accesses otherwise you may run into situation where the thread currently updates something in your cache while you i.e. retrieve some data. The result may produce rather unexpected results here.

I'd argue that such real-time clean-up is usually not necessary and as such I'd handle the cleanup basically in the `get(key)` method which might therefore look something like this:

```java
@Nullable
public V get(@Nonnull final K key) {
    if (!this.lookupMap.containsKey(key)) {
        return null;
    }

    final SoftReference<CacheEntry<K, V>> entry = this.lookupMap.get(key);
    this.entryList.remove(entry);
    final Instant validTill = entry.get().validTill();
    if (validTill != null) {
        final Instant now = Instant.now();
        if (now.isBefore(validTill)) {
            this.entryList.addFirst(entry);
            return entry.get().value();
        } else {
            this.lookupMap.remove(entry.get().key());
        }
    } else {
        this.entryList.addFirst(entry);
        return entry.get().value();
    }
    return null;
}
```

This method will basically remove entries that are literally to old only when you directly look them up. If you don't access these elements anyway they over time will get target for being removed and replaced by other entries anyway and if the JVM needs more memory the GC could free large objects due to the usage of soft references.

Not performing real-time cleanup but a cleanup on entry access may of course return incorrect results on methods like `containsKey(key)` or `size()` that still would propagate the calls to the underlying map or list, but as mentioned before, these methods are not the main concern of a cache and usually not of much interest also. That's why I proposed to basically focus the methods on the main task at hand and remove everything you don't really need in the first place.

This remove-old-entries-on-access strategy basically allows you to ship a fully unsynchronized cache implementation to users, hopefully with the `@NotThreadSafe` annotation assigned. A subclass of that implementation simply could add synchronization to the `put(...)` and `get(key)` methods and this implementation should be good to go for multi-thread usage as well.

Answer (score 2):

Imagining some use cases for the implementation I note following missing features:

Auto refresh being a client choice it should support repeatable calls, that is support restarting.

With auto refresh off it might worth supporting on demand refresh.

It is common for cache implementation to support evict a cache entry by its key.

Answer (score 1):

Java API includes an LRU implementation called `WeakHashMap`.

Comment: A `WeakHashMap` allows the garbage collector to collect any KEY that has no further strong or soft references left in the application. There is actually no guarantee by the JVM when weakly reachable objects will be collected. An LRU cache is also more like a linked list where elements are sorted based on their last usage and on adding new elements and no further space left in the cache the least recently used element is removed and the new item added at the front of the list. See also [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1802879/1377895) why `WeahHashMap` is no LRU cache replacement

Comment: So you are claiming this answer to be wrong ? @RomanVottner

Comment: @BillalBegueradj from a standpoint that `WeakHashMap` is not a Cache implementation, yes

Comment: @RomanVottner I saw the post yesterday, and the score has increased with no downvotes. Please downvote posts which are bad.

Comment: @Peilonrayz I initially upvoted the post as I had the same assumption as the poster obviously has. I then continued my work and when I rethought what a `WeahHashMap` actually is and then did some further research my upvote was already locked and thus I can't downvote the answer

Comment: It's not an answer to the question OP asked, is it?

Answer (score 1):

Implementation could be refactored to follow clean code and some of practic programmer principles.

The auto refresh is a two responsibilities concern, a scheduler and a code snippet to run, that should have their distinct implementations a scheduler and a runnable, according to single responsibility principle (SRP)...

```
class DaemonRunner {

    long runIntervalMillis;
    private boolean autoRefresh;
    private Thread runner;
    private Runnable scheduled;

    public DaemonRunner(long runIntervalMillis) {
        this.runIntervalMillis = runIntervalMillis;
    }

    public void on() {
        if ( runner != null && runner.isAlive() ) { return; }
            
        start();
    }

    public void off() { autoRefresh = false; }

    public void schedule(Runnable toRun) { this.scheduled = toRun; }

    private void start() {
        Runnable backgroundRefreshnTask = () -> {
            while (autoRefresh) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(this.runIntervalMillis);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
                this.scheduled.run();
            }
        };

        this.runner = new Thread(backgroundRefreshnTask);
        this.runner.setDaemon(true);
        this.runner.start();
    }
}
```

Cache entry life span and refresh interval are two distinct concerns although it might happen to have equal values they are different from each other.  For convenience constants could be defined for each…

```
private static final long ENTRY_LIFE_SPAN_MILLIS = 5_000_000_000L;
private static final long REFRESH_INTERVAL_MILLIS = 5_000_000_000L;
```

To avoid code duplication follow don't repeat yourself (DRY) principle and define a single constructor…

```
private Cache(int capacity, long entryLifeSpanMillis) {
    this.capacity = capacity;
    this.entryLifeSpanMillis = entryLifeSpanMillis;
    this.cacheLookup = new HashMap<>(capacity);
    this.cacheList = new LinkedList<>();
}
```

To facilitate cache instantiation provide static factory methods in `Cache` class...

```
public static <T, U> Cache<T, U> autoRefreshable() { ... }

public static <T, U> Cache<T, U> refreshable() { ... }

public static <T, U> Cache<T, U> autoRefreshable(int capacity) { ... }
    
public static <T, U> Cache<T, U> refreshable(int capacity) { ... }
```

…and to develop a cache instantiation domain specific language (DSL) implement builder with fluent interface design patterns for auto refresh options...

```
class AutoRefresh {

    private Runnable on;
    private Runnable off;
    private Consumer<Long> refreshInterval;

    public static final AutoRefresh on(Runnable on) {

        return new AutoRefresh(on);
    }

    public AutoRefresh(Runnable on) { this.on = on; }
        
    public AutoRefresh off(Runnable off) { this.off = off; return this; }
    
    public AutoRefresh interval(Consumer<Long> interval) {
        this.refreshInterval = interval;
        return this;
    }

    public RefreshCommand command() {
        return new RefreshCommand(this.on, this.off, this.refreshInterval);
    }
}

class RefreshCommand {

    private Runnable on;
    private Runnable off;
    private Consumer<Long> refreshInterval;

    public RefreshCommand(Runnable on, Runnable off, Consumer<Long> refreshInterval) {
        this.on = on;
        this.off = off;
        this.refreshInterval = refreshInterval;
    }

    RefreshCommand on() { this.on.run(); return this; }

    RefreshCommand off() { this.off.run(); return this; }

    RefreshCommand interval(long millis) {
        this.refreshInterval.accept(millis);
        return this;
    }
}
```

... and the implementation could change to…

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

class Cache<K, V> {

    private static final int CAPACITY = 1024;   
    private static final long ENTRY_LIFE_SPAN_MILLIS = 5_000_000_000L;
    private static final long REFRESH_INTERVAL_MILLIS = 5_000_000_000L;

    private final HashMap<K, V> cacheLookup;
    private final LinkedList<CacheEntry<K, V>> cacheList;
    private int capacity;
    private long entryLifeSpanMillis;
    private DaemonRunner refresher;
    private RefreshCommand autoRefresh;

    public static <T, U> Cache<T, U> autoRefreshable() {

        final Cache<T, U> cache = Cache.autoRefreshable(CAPACITY);
        cache.refresher = new DaemonRunner(REFRESH_INTERVAL_MILLIS);
        cache.refresher.schedule( () -> { cache.refresh(); } );
        cache.autoRefresh = AutoRefresh.on(() -> { cache.refresher.on(); } )
                                       .off(() -> { cache.refresher.off(); })
                                       .interval( (refreshIntervalMillis) -> { cache.refresher.runIntervalMillis = refreshIntervalMillis; } )
                                       .command();
        cache.autoRefresh().get().on();

        return cache;
    }

    public static <T, U> Cache<T, U> refreshable() {

        return Cache.refreshable(Cache.CAPACITY);
    }

    public static <T, U> Cache<T, U> autoRefreshable(int capacity) {

        final Cache<T, U> cache = new Cache<T, U>(capacity, Cache.ENTRY_LIFE_SPAN_MILLIS);
        cache.refresher = new DaemonRunner(5_000_000_000L);
        cache.autoRefresh = AutoRefresh.on(() -> { cache.refresher.on(); } )
                                       .off(() -> { cache.refresher.off(); })
                                       .interval( (refreshIntervalMillis) -> { cache.refresher.runIntervalMillis = refreshIntervalMillis; } )
                                      .command();

        cache.autoRefresh().get().on();

        return cache;
    }

    public static <T, U> Cache<T, U> refreshable(int capacity) {
        
        return new Cache<T, U>(capacity, Cache.ENTRY_LIFE_SPAN_MILLIS);
    }

    private Cache(int capacity, long entryLifeSpanMillis) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
        this.entryLifeSpanMillis = entryLifeSpanMillis;
        this.cacheLookup = new HashMap<>(capacity);
        this.cacheList = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    public void put(K key, V value) {
    
        if ( cacheList.size() >= capacity ) { evictItem(); }

        cacheLookup.put(key, value);
        cacheList.add(new CacheEntry<>(key, value, this.entryLifeSpanMillis));
    }

    public V get(K key) {
        return cacheLookup.get(key);
    }

    public boolean containsKey(K key) {
        return cacheLookup.containsKey(key);
    }

    public int size() {
        return cacheList.size();
    }

    public void clear() {
        cacheLookup.clear();
        cacheList.clear();
    }

    public void view() {
        for ( CacheEntry<K, V> entryItem : cacheList ) {
            System.out.println("Key: " + entryItem.key + " | Value: " + entryItem.value);
        }
    }

    public Optional<RefreshCommand> autoRefresh() {

        return Optional.ofNullable(this.autoRefresh);
    }

    public void refresh() {
        while ( !cacheList.isEmpty() && !cacheList.peekFirst().isAlive() ) {
            evictItem();
        }
    }

    public void evict(K key) {

        this.cacheLookup.remove(key);

        for ( int index = 0; index < this.cacheList.size(); index++ ) {
            
            CacheEntry<K, V> cacheEntry = this.cacheList.get(index);
            if (cacheEntry.key.equals(key)) {
                this.cacheList.remove(index);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void evictItem() {
        CacheEntry<K, V> item = cacheList.removeFirst();
        cacheLookup.remove(item.key);
    }

    private static class AutoRefresh {

    private Runnable on;
    private Runnable off;
    private Consumer<Long> refreshInterval;

    public static final AutoRefresh on(Runnable on) {

        return new AutoRefresh(on);
    }

    AutoRefresh(Runnable on) {
        this.on = on;
    }

    public AutoRefresh off(Runnable off) {
        this.off = off;
        return this;
    }

    public AutoRefresh interval(Consumer<Long> interval) {
        this.refreshInterval = interval;
        return this;
    }

    public RefreshCommand command() {
        return new RefreshCommand(this.on, this.off, this.refreshInterval);
    }
}

private static class RefreshCommand {

    private Runnable on;
    private Runnable off;
    private Consumer<Long> refreshInterval;

    RefreshCommand(Runnable on, Runnable off, Consumer<Long> refreshInterval) {
        this.on = on;
        this.off = off;
        this.refreshInterval = refreshInterval;
    }

    RefreshCommand on() {
        this.on.run();
        return this;
    }

    RefreshCommand off() {
        this.off.run();
        return this;
    }

    RefreshCommand interval(long millis) {
        this.refreshInterval.accept(millis);
        return this;
    }
}

private static class DaemonRunner {

    
    long runIntervalMillis;
    private boolean autoRefresh;
    private Thread runner;
    private Runnable scheduled;

    DaemonRunner(long runIntervalMillis) {
        this.runIntervalMillis = runIntervalMillis;
    }
        
    public void on() {
        if (runner != null && runner.isAlive()) {
            return;
        }
        start();
    }

    public void off() {
        autoRefresh = false;
    }

    public void schedule(Runnable toRun) {
        this.scheduled = toRun;
    }

    private void start() {
        Runnable backgroundRefreshnTask = () -> {
            while (autoRefresh) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(this.runIntervalMillis);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                this.scheduled.run();
            }
        };

        this.runner = new Thread(backgroundRefreshnTask);
        runner.setDaemon(true);
        runner.start();
    }
}

private static class CacheEntry<K, V> {

        K key;
        V value;
        private long createdTime, lifeSpan;

        CacheEntry(K key, V value, long lifeSpan) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
            this.createdTime = System.nanoTime();
            this.lifeSpan = lifeSpan;
        }

        public boolean isAlive() {
            return System.nanoTime() - this.createdTime + 1 > this.lifeSpan;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Right now, the class is not thread safe but would like to add that functionality in the future.

Before addressing concurrency heed cache’s purpose that according to wikipedia page…

> In computing, a cache is a hardware or software component that stores data so that future requests for that data can be served faster;

… and cache operations use cases (1) `get(key)` intensively used (2) `put(key, item)` moderately used (3) `remove(key)` scarcely used.

To have a fast data consistent cache put operation seems appropriate to keep data consistent with low penalty over performance.

Improvement addressing maintainability and extensibility could be achieved following SOLID, DRY, abstraction and encapsulation principles and implementing static factory method, builder and fluent interface design patterns.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

class Cache<K, V> {

    private static final int CAPACITY = 1024;   
    private static final long ENTRY_LIFE_SPAN_MILLIS = 5_000_000_000L;
    private static final long REFRESH_INTERVAL_MILLIS = 5_000_000_000L;

    private final HashMap<K, V> cacheLookup;
    private final LinkedList<CacheEntry<K, V>> cacheList;
    private int capacity;
    private long entryLifeSpanMillis;
    private DaemonRunner refresher;
    private RefreshCommand autoRefresh;

    public static <T, U> Cache<T, U> autoRefreshable() {

        final Cache<T, U> cache = Cache.autoRefreshable(CAPACITY);
        cache.refresher = new DaemonRunner(REFRESH_INTERVAL_MILLIS);
        cache.refresher.schedule( () -> { cache.refresh(); } );
        cache.autoRefresh = AutoRefresh.on(() -> { cache.refresher.on(); } )
                                       .off(() -> { cache.refresher.off(); })
                                       .interval((refreshIntervalMillis) -> { 
                                            cache.refresher.runIntervalMillis = refreshIntervalMillis; 
                                        })
                                       .command();
        cache.autoRefresh().get().on();

        return cache;
    }

    public static <T, U> Cache<T, U> refreshable() {

        return Cache.refreshable(Cache.CAPACITY);
    }

    public static <T, U> Cache<T, U> autoRefreshable(int capacity) {

        final Cache<T, U> cache = new Cache<T, U>(capacity, Cache.ENTRY_LIFE_SPAN_MILLIS);
        cache.refresher = new DaemonRunner(REFRESH_INTERVAL_MILLIS);
        cache.autoRefresh = AutoRefresh.on(() -> { cache.refresher.on(); })
                                       .off(() -> { cache.refresher.off(); })
                                       .interval((refreshIntervalMillis) -> { 
                                            cache.refresher.runIntervalMillis = refreshIntervalMillis; })
                                       .command();

        cache.autoRefresh().get().on();

        return cache;
    }

    public static <T, U> Cache<T, U> refreshable(int capacity) {
        
        return new Cache<T, U>(capacity, Cache.ENTRY_LIFE_SPAN_MILLIS);
    }

    private Cache(int capacity, long entryLifeSpanMillis) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
        this.entryLifeSpanMillis = entryLifeSpanMillis;
        this.cacheLookup = new HashMap<>(capacity);
        this.cacheList = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    public void put(K key, V value) {       
        if ( cacheLookup.containsKey(key) ) { evict(key); }
        if ( cacheList.size() >= capacity ) { 
            refresh();
            if ( cacheList.size() >= capacity ) { return; }
        }

        cacheList.add(new CacheEntry<>(key, value, this.entryLifeSpanMillis));
        cacheLookup.put(key, value);
    }

    public V get(K key) {
        return cacheLookup.get(key);
    }

    public boolean containsKey(K key) {
        return cacheLookup.containsKey(key);
    }

    public int size() {
        return cacheList.size();
    }

    public void clear() {
        cacheLookup.clear();
        cacheList.clear();
    }

    public void view() {
        for ( CacheEntry<K, V> entryItem : cacheList ) {
            System.out.println( "Key: " + entryItem.key 
                              + " | Value: " + entryItem.value );
        }
    }

    public Optional<RefreshCommand> autoRefresh() {

        return Optional.ofNullable(this.autoRefresh);
    }

    public void refresh() {
        while ( !cacheList.isEmpty() && !cacheList.peekFirst().isAlive() ) {
            evictItem();
        }
    }

    public void evict(K key) {
        this.cacheLookup.remove(key);
        for ( int index = 0; index < this.cacheList.size(); index++ ) {
            if ( this.cacheList.get(index).key.equals(key) ) {
                this.cacheList.remove(index);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void evictItem() {
        CacheEntry<K, V> item = cacheList.removeFirst();
        cacheLookup.remove(item.key);
    }

    private static class AutoRefresh {

    private Runnable on;
    private Runnable off;
    private Consumer<Long> refreshInterval;

    public static final AutoRefresh on(Runnable on) {

        return new AutoRefresh(on);
    }

    private AutoRefresh(Runnable on) {
        this.on = on;
    }

    AutoRefresh off(Runnable off) {
        this.off = off;
        return this;
    }

    AutoRefresh interval(Consumer<Long> interval) {
        this.refreshInterval = interval;
        return this;
    }

    RefreshCommand command() {
        return new RefreshCommand(this.on, this.off, this.refreshInterval);
    }
}

private static class RefreshCommand {

    private Runnable on;
    private Runnable off;
    private Consumer<Long> refreshInterval;

    private RefreshCommand(Runnable on, Runnable off, Consumer<Long> refreshInterval) {
        this.on = on;
        this.off = off;
        this.refreshInterval = refreshInterval;
    }

    RefreshCommand on() {
        this.on.run();
        return this;
    }

    RefreshCommand off() {
        this.off.run();
        return this;
    }

    RefreshCommand interval(long millis) {
        this.refreshInterval.accept(millis);
        return this;
    }
}

private static class DaemonRunner {

    long runIntervalMillis;
    private boolean autoRefresh;
    private Thread runner;
    private Runnable scheduled;

    DaemonRunner(long runIntervalMillis) {
        this.runIntervalMillis = runIntervalMillis;
    }
        
    void on() {
        if (runner != null && runner.isAlive()) {
            return;
        }
        start();
    }

    void off() {
        autoRefresh = false;
    }

    void schedule(Runnable toRun) {
        this.scheduled = toRun;
    }

    private void start() {
        Runnable backgroundRefreshnTask = () -> {
            while (autoRefresh) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(this.runIntervalMillis);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                this.scheduled.run();
            }
        };

        this.runner = new Thread(backgroundRefreshnTask);
        runner.setDaemon(true);
        runner.start();
    }
}

private static class CacheEntry<K, V> {

        K key;
        V value;
        private long createdTime, lifeSpan;

        CacheEntry(K key, V value, long lifeSpan) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
            this.createdTime = System.nanoTime();
            this.lifeSpan = lifeSpan;
        }

        boolean isAlive() {
            return System.nanoTime() - this.createdTime + 1 > this.lifeSpan;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go play, seeming an implementation for academic purpose it offers potential to experiment various classes the Java API includes and/or design patterns. Couple of examples could be to implement refresher (1) using `ScheduledExecutorService` returned by `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(threadFactory)` that in case might be to heavy for the actual use case (2) using strategy design pattern by enhancing the daemon runner with events.

Following example is for the second option additionally using variable length argument list and a slightly different DSL than the one from the description (`dispose` instead of `evict`)...

```
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

class Cache<K, V> {

    private static final int CAPACITY = 1024;
    private static final long ENTRY_LIFE_SPAN_MILLIS = 5_000_000_000L;
    private static final long REFRESH_INTERVAL_MILLIS = 5_000_000_000L;

    private final HashMap<K, V> cacheLookup;
    private final LinkedList<CacheEntry<K, V>> cacheList;
    private int capacity;
    private long entryLifeSpanMillis;
    private DaemonRunner refresher;
    private RefreshCommand autoRefresh;

    public static <T, U> Cache<T, U> autoRefreshable() {

        final Cache<T, U> cache = Cache.autoRefreshable(CAPACITY);
        cache.refresher = new DaemonRunner(REFRESH_INTERVAL_MILLIS);
        cache.refresher.schedule(() -> {
            cache.refresh();
        });
        cache.autoRefresh = AutoRefresh.on(() -> { cache.refresher.on(); })
                                       .off(() -> { cache.refresher.off(); })
                                       .interval((refreshIntervalMillis) -> { 
                                           cache.refresher.runIntervalMillis = refreshIntervalMillis;
                                        })
                                       .command();
        cache.autoRefresh().get().on();

        return cache;
    }

    public static <T, U> Cache<T, U> refreshable() {

        return Cache.refreshable(Cache.CAPACITY);
    }

    public static <T, U> Cache<T, U> autoRefreshable(int capacity) {

        final Cache<T, U> cache = new Cache<T, U>(capacity, Cache.ENTRY_LIFE_SPAN_MILLIS);
        cache.refresher = new DaemonRunner(REFRESH_INTERVAL_MILLIS);
        cache.autoRefresh = AutoRefresh.on(() -> { cache.refresher.on(); })
                                       .off(() -> { cache.refresher.off();})
                                       .interval((refreshIntervalMillis) -> {
                                            cache.refresher.runIntervalMillis = refreshIntervalMillis;
                                        })
                                       .command();
        cache.autoRefresh().get().on();

        return cache;
    }

    public static <T, U> Cache<T, U> refreshable(int capacity) {

        return new Cache<T, U>(capacity, Cache.ENTRY_LIFE_SPAN_MILLIS);
    }

    private Cache(int capacity, long entryLifeSpanMillis) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
        this.entryLifeSpanMillis = entryLifeSpanMillis;
        cacheLookup = new HashMap<>(capacity);
        cacheList = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    public void put(K key, V value) {

        if (cacheLookup.containsKey(key)) { return; }
        if (cacheList.size() >= capacity) {
            refresh();
            if (cacheList.size() >= capacity) { return; }
        }

        cacheList.add(new CacheEntry<>(key, value, this.entryLifeSpanMillis));
        cacheLookup.put(key, value);
    }

    public V get(K key) {
        return cacheLookup.get(key);
    }

    public boolean containsKey(K key) {
        return cacheLookup.containsKey(key);
    }

    public int size() {
        return cacheList.size();
    }

    public void clear() {
        cacheLookup.clear();
        cacheList.clear();
    }

    public void view() {
        for (CacheEntry<K, V> entryItem : cacheList) {
            System.out.println( "Key: " + entryItem.key 
                              + " | Value: " + entryItem.value );
        }
    }

    public Optional<RefreshCommand> autoRefresh() {

        return Optional.ofNullable(this.autoRefresh);
    }

    public void refresh() {
        while (!cacheList.isEmpty() && !cacheList.peekFirst().isAlive()) {
            disposeItem();
        }
    }

    public void dispose(K key) {
        this.cacheLookup.remove(key);
        for (int index = 0; index < this.cacheList.size(); index++) {
            if (this.cacheList.get(index).key.equals(key)) {
                this.cacheList.remove(index);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void disposeItem() {
        CacheEntry<K, V> item = cacheList.removeFirst();
        cacheLookup.remove(item.key);
    }

    private static class AutoRefresh {

        private Runnable on;
        private Runnable off;
        private Consumer<Long> refreshInterval;

        public static final AutoRefresh on(Runnable on) {

            return new AutoRefresh(on);
        }

        private AutoRefresh(Runnable on) {
            this.on = on;
        }

        AutoRefresh off(Runnable off) {
            this.off = off;
            return this;
        }

        AutoRefresh interval(Consumer<Long> interval) {
            this.refreshInterval = interval;
            return this;
        }

        RefreshCommand command() {
            return new RefreshCommand(this.on, this.off, this.refreshInterval);
        }
    }

    private static class RefreshCommand {

        private Runnable on;
        private Runnable off;
        private Consumer<Long> refreshInterval;

        private RefreshCommand(Runnable on
                             , Runnable off
                             , Consumer<Long> refreshInterval) {
            this.on = on;
            this.off = off;
            this.refreshInterval = refreshInterval;
        }

        RefreshCommand on() {
            this.on.run();
            return this;
        }

        RefreshCommand off() {
            this.off.run();
            return this;
        }

        RefreshCommand interval(long millis) {
            this.refreshInterval.accept(millis);
            return this;
        }
    }

    private static class DaemonRunner {

        private interface RunnerEvent { RunnerEvent on(); }

        private static class StartEvent implements RunnerEvent {

            private Runnable toRun;

            static StartEvent of(Runnable toRun) { return new StartEvent(toRun); }

            private StartEvent(Runnable toRun) { this.toRun = toRun; }

            @Override
            public RunnerEvent on() {
                Thread runner = new Thread(this.toRun);
                runner.setDaemon(true);
                runner.start();
                return this;
            }
        }

        private static class EmptyRunnerEvent implements RunnerEvent {

            @Override
            public RunnerEvent on() { return this; }
        }
        
        private static class EventStack {
            
            static EventStack of(RunnerEvent... events) {
                
                return new EventStack(Arrays.asList(events));
            }
            
            private Deque<RunnerEvent> runnerEvents;
            
            EventStack(List<RunnerEvent> events) {
                this.runnerEvents = new ArrayDeque<>(events);
            }
            
            void on() {
                this.runnerEvents.add(this.runnerEvents.poll().on());
            }
        }
        
        long runIntervalMillis;
        private boolean autoRefresh;
        private Runnable scheduled;
        private EventStack runnerEvents;

        DaemonRunner(long runIntervalMillis) {
            this.autoRefresh = true;
            this.runIntervalMillis = runIntervalMillis;
            this.runnerEvents = EventStack.of(this.getStartEvent(), new EmptyRunnerEvent());
        }

        void on() {
            if ( this.autoRefresh ) { return; }
            this.autoRefresh = true;
            this.runnerEvents.on();
        }

        void off() { this.autoRefresh = false; }

        void schedule(Runnable toRun) { this.scheduled = toRun; }

        private RunnerEvent getStartEvent() {
            Runnable backgroundRefreshnTask = () -> {
                while (autoRefresh) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(this.runIntervalMillis);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    this.scheduled.run();
                }
            };

            return StartEvent.of(backgroundRefreshnTask);
        }
    }

    private static class CacheEntry<K, V> {

        K key;
        V value;
        private long createdTime, lifeSpan;

        CacheEntry(K key, V value, long lifeSpan) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
            this.createdTime = System.nanoTime();
            this.lifeSpan = lifeSpan;
        }

        boolean isAlive() {
            return System.nanoTime() - this.createdTime + 1 > this.lifeSpan;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is this ??

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `autoRefresh` flag on `false` while the thread is sleeping has the side effect of running a cache refresh before stopping the thread, to prevent this side effect the exception handling branch should additional test the flag and exist the loop when is the case.

With the bounded capacity it could be useful to signal the client whether a value has been or hasn't been added to the cache through the `put` method returning true when the value has been added or false otherwise.

```
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

class Cache<K, V> {

    private static final int CAPACITY = 1024;
    private static final long ENTRY_LIFE_SPAN_MILLIS = 5_000_000_000L;
    private static final long REFRESH_INTERVAL_MILLIS = 5_000_000_000L;

    private final HashMap<K, V> cacheLookup;
    private final LinkedList<CacheEntry<K, V>> cacheList;
    private int capacity;
    private long entryLifeSpanMillis;
    private DaemonRunner refresher;
    private RefreshCommand autoRefresher;

    public static <T, U> Cache<T, U> autoRefreshable() {

        final Cache<T, U> cache = Cache.autoRefreshable(CAPACITY);
        cache.refresher = new DaemonRunner(REFRESH_INTERVAL_MILLIS);
        cache.refresher.schedule(() -> {
            cache.refresh();
        });
        cache.autoRefresher = AutoRefresh.on(() -> { cache.refresher.on(); })
                                       .off(() -> { cache.refresher.off(); })
                                       .interval((refreshIntervalMillis) -> { 
                                           cache.refresher.runIntervalMillis = refreshIntervalMillis;
                                        })
                                       .command();
        cache.autoRefresh().get().on();

        return cache;
    }

    public static <T, U> Cache<T, U> refreshable() {

        return Cache.refreshable(Cache.CAPACITY);
    }

    public static <T, U> Cache<T, U> autoRefreshable(int capacity) {

        final Cache<T, U> cache = new Cache<T, U>(capacity, Cache.ENTRY_LIFE_SPAN_MILLIS);
        cache.refresher = new DaemonRunner(REFRESH_INTERVAL_MILLIS);
        cache.autoRefresher = AutoRefresh.on(() -> { cache.refresher.on(); })
                                       .off(() -> { cache.refresher.off();})
                                       .interval((refreshIntervalMillis) -> {
                                            cache.refresher.runIntervalMillis = refreshIntervalMillis;
                                        })
                                       .command();
        cache.autoRefresh().get().on();

        return cache;
    }

    public static <T, U> Cache<T, U> refreshable(int capacity) {

        return new Cache<T, U>(capacity, Cache.ENTRY_LIFE_SPAN_MILLIS);
    }

    private Cache(int capacity, long entryLifeSpanMillis) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
        this.entryLifeSpanMillis = entryLifeSpanMillis;
        cacheLookup = new HashMap<>(capacity);
        cacheList = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    public boolean put(K key, V value) {

        if (cacheLookup.containsKey(key)) { return false; }
        if (cacheList.size() >= capacity) {
            refresh();
            if (cacheList.size() >= capacity) { return false; }
        }

        cacheList.add(new CacheEntry<>(key, value, this.entryLifeSpanMillis));
        cacheLookup.put(key, value);
        
        return true;
    }

    public V get(K key) {
        return cacheLookup.get(key);
    }

    public boolean containsKey(K key) {
        return cacheLookup.containsKey(key);
    }

    public int size() {
        return cacheList.size();
    }

    public void clear() {
        cacheLookup.clear();
        cacheList.clear();
    }

    public void view() {
        for (CacheEntry<K, V> entryItem : cacheList) {
            System.out.println( "Key: " + entryItem.key 
                              + " | Value: " + entryItem.value );
        }
    }

    public Optional<RefreshCommand> autoRefresh() {

        return Optional.ofNullable(this.autoRefresher);
    }

    public void refresh() {
        while (!cacheList.isEmpty() && !cacheList.peekFirst().isAlive()) {
            disposeItem();
        }
    }

    public void dispose(K key) {
        this.cacheLookup.remove(key);
        for (int index = 0; index < this.cacheList.size(); index++) {
            if (this.cacheList.get(index).key.equals(key)) {
                this.cacheList.remove(index);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void disposeItem() {
        CacheEntry<K, V> item = cacheList.removeFirst();
        cacheLookup.remove(item.key);
    }

    private static class AutoRefresh {

        private Runnable on;
        private Runnable off;
        private Consumer<Long> refreshInterval;

        public static final AutoRefresh on(Runnable on) {

            return new AutoRefresh(on);
        }

        private AutoRefresh(Runnable on) {
            this.on = on;
        }

        AutoRefresh off(Runnable off) {
            this.off = off;
            return this;
        }

        AutoRefresh interval(Consumer<Long> interval) {
            this.refreshInterval = interval;
            return this;
        }

        RefreshCommand command() {
            return new RefreshCommand(this.on, this.off, this.refreshInterval);
        }
    }

    private static class RefreshCommand {

        private Runnable on;
        private Runnable off;
        private Consumer<Long> refreshInterval;

        private RefreshCommand(Runnable on
                             , Runnable off
                             , Consumer<Long> refreshInterval) {
            this.on = on;
            this.off = off;
            this.refreshInterval = refreshInterval;
        }

        RefreshCommand on() {
            this.on.run();
            return this;
        }

        RefreshCommand off() {
            this.off.run();
            return this;
        }

        RefreshCommand interval(long millis) {
            this.refreshInterval.accept(millis);
            return this;
        }
    }

    private static class DaemonRunner {

        private interface RunnerEvent { void on(); }

        private static class StartEvent implements RunnerEvent {

            private Runnable toRun;

            static StartEvent of(Runnable toRun) { return new StartEvent(toRun); }

            private StartEvent(Runnable toRun) { this.toRun = toRun; }

            @Override
            public void on() {
                Thread runner = new Thread(this.toRun);
                runner.setDaemon(true);
                runner.start();
            }
        }

        private static class EmptyRunnerEvent implements RunnerEvent {

            @Override
            public void on() { }
        }
        
        private static class EventStack {
            
            static EventStack of(RunnerEvent... events) {
                
                return new EventStack(Arrays.asList(events));
            }
            
            private Deque<RunnerEvent> runnerEvents;
            
            EventStack(List<RunnerEvent> events) {
                this.runnerEvents = new ArrayDeque<>(events);
            }
            
            void on() {
                RunnerEvent runnerEvent = this.runnerEvents.poll();
                this.runnerEvents.add(runnerEvent);
                runnerEvent.on();
            }
        }
        
        long runIntervalMillis;
        private boolean autoRefresh;
        private Runnable scheduled;
        private EventStack runnerEvents;

        DaemonRunner(long runIntervalMillis) {
            this.autoRefresh = true;
            this.runIntervalMillis = runIntervalMillis;
            this.runnerEvents = EventStack.of(this.getStartEvent(), new EmptyRunnerEvent());
        }

        void on() {
            if ( this.autoRefresh ) { return; }
            this.autoRefresh = true;
            this.runnerEvents.on();
        }

        void off() { this.autoRefresh = false; }

        void schedule(Runnable toRun) { this.scheduled = toRun; }

        private RunnerEvent getStartEvent() {
            Runnable backgroundRefreshnTask = () -> {
                while (autoRefresh) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(this.runIntervalMillis);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        if ( !autoRefresh ) { break; }
                    }

                    this.scheduled.run();
                }
            };

            return StartEvent.of(backgroundRefreshnTask);
        }
    }

    private static class CacheEntry<K, V> {

        K key;
        V value;
        private long createdTime, lifeSpan;

        CacheEntry(K key, V value, long lifeSpan) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
            this.createdTime = System.nanoTime();
            this.lifeSpan = lifeSpan;
        }

        boolean isAlive() {
            return System.nanoTime() - this.createdTime + 1 > this.lifeSpan;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are the same person who answered this multiple times without being registered. Not sure why you are doing this